# Fluent Nhibernate Connect to Firebird

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, firebird

I'm having trouble getting a connection to a Firebird database.  I can't seem to find too much information on Fluent NHibernate and Firebird on the Internet which lead me to here.

Can anyone provide any insight on how to connect Fluent NHibernate to a Firebird database in C#?  I'm specifically writing a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything specific to Fluent nHibernate that causes problems with Firebird or any other database for that matter - that's the point of nHibernate, and FnH is just a layer above it.

If you post some errors someone might be able to better help you, because it's impossible to know what it is that's wrong. Can you connect to Firebird through a normal NH mapping in your current environment, for example?

Comment: I apologize. I didn't have all the required dlls for FluentNHibernate associated with my project which was giving me an obscure error.